# how to group data by 7 days and output at first day of each 7 days?

Tags: oracle

I am using Oracle SQL, I'd like to group data by week( or # days), then output data the first day of every # of days.

For example,  if I have date from 2022-01-01, to 2022-02-01, I'd like to output data every 7 days like this

2022-01-01, 2022-01-08, 2022-01-15, 2022-01-22, 2022-01-29,

Here is my code for daily data

```
start='2022-01-01'
end='2022-03-01'

   sql = f"""
      SELECT 
         WELL_NAME,
         ROUND(OBV_TIME,'DDD') as "Date",
         DEPTH,
         AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"                
      FROM THERMAL.OFM_TEMPERATURE_V
      WHERE
         AREA_NAME = 'Wolf Lake'
         AND WELL_NAME = '{well}'
         AND OBV_TIME >= TO_DATE('{start}', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         AND OBV_TIME <= TO_DATE('{end}','YYYY-MM-DD')
         AND DEPTH>={dts_well_depth_min}

      GROUP BY WELL_NAME, ROUND(OBV_TIME,'DDD'), DEPTH
         """
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation (or template strings) to build queries; that is how you get SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use parametrized queries and bind variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRUNC(obv_time, 'IW')` to truncate your date to the start of the ISO week (midnight on Monday):

```py
sql = """
SELECT WELL_NAME,
       TRUNC(OBV_TIME, 'IW') as "Date",
       DEPTH,
       AVG(TEMPERATURE) as "TEMPERATURE"                
FROM   THERMAL.OFM_TEMPERATURE_V
WHERE  AREA_NAME = 'Wolf Lake'
AND    WELL_NAME = ?
AND    OBV_TIME >= ?
AND    OBV_TIME <= ?
AND    DEPTH    >= ?
GROUP BY
       WELL_NAME,
       TRUNC(OBV_TIME,'IW'),
       DEPTH
"""
```

Also, it is bad practice to use string concatenation or template strings to build queries as it introduces SQL injection vulnerabilities. You should use parametrized queries (using either `?` for `:identifier` for the parameters) and then pass in the parameters using bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help if you join this to your view.

```
with params (st, en , gr) as
    (select 
        to_date('2022-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),--start day
        to_date('2022-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),--end day
        7  --group size
        from dual)  
select 
    p1.st + level-1 day,
    p1.st + level-1 - mod(level-1, p1.gr) first_day_in_group,
    decode(mod(level-1, p1.gr),0,'X') is_first_day_in_group
from params p1
connect by level <= p1.en - p1.st;
```

Result:

```
DAY                  FIRST_DAY_IN_GROUP   IS_FIRST_DAY_IN_GROU
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
01.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00     X                   
02.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
03.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
04.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
05.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
06.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
07.01.2022 00:00     01.01.2022 00:00                         
08.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00     X                   
09.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
10.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
11.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
12.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
13.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
14.01.2022 00:00     08.01.2022 00:00                         
15.01.2022 00:00     15.01.2022 00:00     X                   
16.01.2022 00:00     15.01.2022 00:00     
...
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will look at it today and let you know, thank you!